# How can I apply enscript to upwards of 60k files?

Tags: bash, arguments, enscript

I want to apply Gnu enscript on a large collection of files (every file tracked by git in the current Linux kernel). I have just for the hell of it. However, I've tried various things to pass those files as arguments such as a python script and `$(foo)`, but it says that I am giving it too many arguments. For example, if I put the names of all the files into `files.txt`, one per line, then invoke `enscript --color --toc -o out.ps $(<files.txt)`, it prints the error. The same argument list runs just fine with `echo`. To solve this issue, I have tried to add to enscript the ability to read the files to process from a file, but I can't get the enscript source to compile before even making any modifications. Is there something that I'm missing or is this impossible?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a sample invocation of `enscript`?

Comment: @tink I added a sample invokation, as well as the source of the files.

Comment: So you want all those files to end up in one postscript file?

Comment: @tink Yes. I know it's completely stupid and useless, but like I said in the question, it's just for curiosity sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many files to fit in one command line (ARG_MAX, about 2 MB on Linux).

There are several ways of dealing with this - the most obvious is to use `find`'s `-exec` option, which will run multiple "batches" of a command with as many filename arguments as will fit within that limit.  e.g.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'enscript --color --toc -o "out.$(date +%s).ps" "$@"' sh {} +
```

You should, of course, use whatever find predicates are required to match your files - e.g. you probably want to exclude the .git directory itself, and maybe include only source-code and other text files.

Note that I've added the current time to the `out.ps` filename.  This is because `find` will run the `sh -c ...` script once per batch of files, and we don't want the second and subsequent batches to overwrite the output from the first batch.   There are other, probably better/prettier, ways of generating a unique output filename per batch of input files, but this is simple and works and demonstrates the principle - and the output filenames will sort in order of creation. Variations (e.g. keeping a counter in a temp file) are left as an exercise for the reader.

BTW, obviously this will generate one postscript output file per batch of input files, each with its own TOC. This is not quite the same as one output file with ALL input files and one TOC. Since `enscript` can't take a list of filenames from either stdin or a file, that's the closest you can get.

---

Another alternative, if you already have the list of files in a NUL-separated file (newline separated should be OK if you are absolutely certain that none of the filenames will ever contain a newline character) is to use `xargs`.

NUL separated:

```
xargs -0r sh -c 'enscript --color --toc -o "out.$(date +%s).ps" "$@"' sh < files.list
```

newline separated:

```
xargs -d '\n' -r sh -c 'enscript --color --toc -o "out.$(date +%s).ps" "$@"' sh < files.list
```

Note: the `-d` and `-r` options require the GNU version of xargs. Some ancient and/or proprietary versions of xargs don't even support `-0`, but you're unlikely to run into one of those.

---

#### How this works:

Both `find` and `xargs` run the specified command with as many arguments as will fit in a command line, and repeat that until all arguments are used.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI, you can get a NUL-separated list (suitable for piping into `xargs -0r ...`.) of all files in the repo with `git ls-tree`'s `-z` option.  e.g. `git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAD -z`.